# Magento 2: Tax by product category by region

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-class, taxes

Tax zones and rules are pretty straight forward in Magento but I am struggling with a final detail.

I have all the tax set up by province in Canada. That's working well. Only one category of product is partially exempt tax in 3 provinces. It's easy to see how to set up a product tax class, but it's not straight forward to figure out how to exempt tax based on a couple regions. 
I'm sure there is something simple I am missing - I don't want the product category to be tax exempt, I only want part of the tax (pst) to be exempt in 3 provinces, but apply in other provinces.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a unique product tax class assigned to the products in this one category, you should be able to use reduced tax rates omitting PST in the 3 provinces. I think you'd have to do the following:

1) Create a new product tax class and assign your products to this tax class.

2) Create a new tax rate for each of the 3 provinces with the partial tax rate, omitting PST.

3) Create a new tax rule for the product tax class with the partial tax rates + full tax rates for other provinces.

I think the key here is providing 2 different rates for those 3 provinces based on the product tax class. This can become tedious with more categories, so beyond this use case you may want to consider [programmatically extending Magento 2's tax calculations](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148327/where-to-override-the-tax-in-magento-2/148685#148685) for custom logic around regions and specific product categories.

Comment: Thank you. I basically ended up creating a new tax rule for those 3 provinces then assigned that tax rule to the products affected. I'll be testing on the next import.